# Как применить фильтр imagefilter в функции?

Tags: php, img, gd

Как ни пытался, ничего не выходит. Вот такой у меня код:

```
public function fileUpload($path)
{
    $fileTmpName = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

    $image = getimagesize($fileTmpName);
    $extension = image_type_to_extension($image[2]);
    $path = 'public/images/uploads/' . uniqid() . $extension;
    
    $params = [
        'id' => null,
        'path' => $path,
    ];

    move_uploaded_file($fileTmpName, $path);

    imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
    imagefilter($path, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
    
    $this->db->query('INSERT INTO `files` VALUES (:id, :path, strftime("%d.%m.%Y %H:%M"))', $params);
    return $this->db->getLastInsertId();
}
```

Прошу помощи!

Comment: @InDevX, а как потом записать?

Comment: `$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path); imagefilter($image, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE); imagejpeg($image);`

Comment: `$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileTmpName); imagefilter($image, ...); $f= fopen($path, 'w'); imagejpeg($image, $f); unlink($fileTmpName)` как-то так должно быть

Comment: @teran можно просто путь передать, не суть.. убивает когда задают вопрос вместо того чтоб пойти в доки смотреть как работает

Comment: @teran — огромнейшее спасибо! Вот так работает. Пойду читать и разбирать всё, что вы посоветовали, для понимания сути.

Comment: @Linne там можно без fopen, передать путь к новому просто. `imagedestroy` в конце еще надо. Ну и собственно, если у вас не только jpeg входе, то мб лучше будет `imagecreatefromstring(file_get_contents($tmpFile))`

Comment: @teran т. е. вот так: `$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileTmpName);
  imagefilter($filter, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
  // $f = fopen($path, 'w');
  imagejpeg($img, $path);
  imagedestroy($fileTmpName);
  // unlink($fileTmpName);`

Comment: @teran нет, на входе исключительно jpeg. Я в валидаторе это реализовал.

Comment: @teran вот так отлично работает: `$filter = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileTmpName);
  imagefilter($filter, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
  imagejpeg($filter, $path);
  imagedestroy($filter);`

Только вот, хотел спросить: `unlink($fileTmpName)` по прежнему нужен?

Answer (score 1):

Функция `imagefilter()` в качестве первого аргумента принимает не путь к картинке, а обьект типа `GdImage`, созданный другой функцией, например, `imagecreatefromjpeg()`.

```
$img = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
imagefilter($img, IMG_FILTER_GRAYSCALE);
imagejpeg($img, $new_path);
```

Comment: Да, я знаю об этом, но как применить в моём случае?

Comment: @Linne, я же показал код, что применить?

Comment: @Linne, я понял, вы спрашиваете, как его сохранить? Дополнил ответ.

Comment: @Linne, можно к новому, можно в тот же писать. Если не указывать, картинка будет просто выводиться в браузере.